# mame - Segmentation fault (Core Dumped) - Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: ubuntu

If i run [MAME](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libs/qt5-default) on a fresh install of Ubuntu server, I see:

```
message Segmentation fault (Core Dumped)
```

If I run this on Ubuntu Desktop (18.04), it starts up okay.

Can anyone tell me what prerequisite(s) I need to install to get MAME started on "Server" ?

(steps/commands entered which work on desktop version):

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install mame && mame
```

Installing [qt5-default](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libs/qt5-default) did not solve the problem, using:

```
sudo apt install qt5-default
```

Installing from the Snap Store also did not solve this, using:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install snapd && sudo snap install mame
```

How else may I troubleshoot this to solve the issue?

Comment: The difference between the two systems (if you have made no changes), will be the desktop software will not be installed for the server. This will include the windowing system. You may have to install it.

Comment: Is the windowing system available for the server version do you know?   My reasons for the not wanting to use the full desktop version are because when i load games or exit out of games, the background of the desktop flashes up for a second before returning into the games list/lobby - which looks a bit naff. I'm also very new to linux and wanted to do this as a learning hobby for the command line, Id feel a better sense of achievement if i complete it restricted to the command line only (simple pleasures! )

Comment: Yes you can install the desktop on the server. The only difference is the default packages that are installed (the server has less). This is the opposite of MS servers that have more (licencing and all that). However I don't know if it is the reason. If you are installing text games, then why would it need a GUI?

Comment: Can you edit the question to show: How you ran the program, the exact output including error messages, and how you installed it.